# Python fight game never ends

Tags: python

I can't find any problems in my game, other than the fact that it won't end. I can't see what is wrong with it.

```
def fight(enemy, playerH, enemyH): #defining a function fight

    slay =True

    def testDeath(pHealth, eHealth, enemy): #defining a function to test if player/enemy is dead
        if pHealth <= 0:
            slay = False
            print"You have lost the fight, better luck next time."
        elif eHealth <= 0:
            slay = False
            print"You have slain the",enemy,". You win! Congratulations!"
        else:
            slay = True
        #end of the testDeath function
    print"You are fighting a",enemy


    while slay:  #while loop to perform the fight
        playerD = randint(0,5)  #making each characters damage using randint
        dragonD = randint(0,7)
        trollD = randint(0,4)


        if  enemy == "troll":
            enemyD = trollD
        elif enemy == "dragon":
            enemyD = dragonD


        print"Your health:",playerH
        print enemy,"'s health:",enemyH
        sleep(1)  #sleep makes next message appear after (1) second(s)


        if playerD == 5 or playerD == 4:  #player's attack
            print"You deal",playerD,"damage points. A critical hit!"
            enemyH = enemyH - playerD  #removing player damage from enemy health
            testDeath(playerH, enemyH, enemy)
            if slay == False: break
            #sleep(1.5)
            #print"The",enemy,"has",enemyH,"health points remaining."
            sleep(2)
        elif playerD == 0:
              print"You attack has missed. You deal 0 damage points."
              sleep(2)
        else:
            print"You deal",playerD,"damage points."
            enemyH = enemyH - playerD
            testDeath(playerH, enemyH, enemy)
            if slay == False: break
            #sleep(1.5)
            #print"The",enemy,"has",enemyH,"health points remaining."
            sleep(2)

        if enemy == "troll":
            if enemyD == 4:
                print"The troll deals 4 damage points. A critical hit!"
                playerH = playerH - enemyD
                testDeath(playerH, enemyH, enemy)
                if slay == False: break
                #sleep(1.5)
                #print"You have",playerH,"health points remaining."
                sleep(2)
            elif enemyD == 0:
                print"The troll's attack  missed. He deals 0 damage points."
                sleep(2)
            else:
                print"The troll deals",enemyD,"damage points."
                playerH = playerH - enemyD
                testDeath(playerH, enemyH, enemy)
                if slay == False: break
                #sleep(1.5)
                #print"You have",playerH,"health points remaining."
                sleep(2)

        elif enemy == "dragon":
            if enemyD == 6 or enemyD == 7:
                print"The dragon deals",enemyD,"damage points. A critical hit!"
                playerH = playerH - enemyD
                testDeath(playerH, enemyH, enemy)
                if slay == False: break
                #sleep(1.5)
                #print"You have",playerH,"health points remaining."
                sleep(2)
            elif enemyD == 0:
                print"The dragon's attack missed. He deals 0 damage points."
                sleep(2)
            else:
                print"The dragon deals",enemyD,"damage points."
                playerH = playerH - enemyD
                testDeath(playerH, enemyH, enemy)
                if slay == False: break
                #sleep(1.5)
                #print"You have",playerH,"health points remaining."
                sleep(2)
```

I know that's a lot of code but I don't think less would be enough. It may be, but as I can't see the problem I don't know what part to post here.

Everything works fine until someone dies. When something dies it will say `"congratulations you win"` but the battle will go on. Can anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `testDeath` function defines its own local `slay`. This is **not** connected to the value that the `while` loop is testing. You need to `return`:

```
def testDeath(pHealth, eHealth, enemy): #defining a function to test if player/enemy is dead
    if pHealth <= 0:
        slay = False
        print"You have lost the fight, better luck next time."
    elif eHealth <= 0:
        slay = False
        print"You have slain the",enemy,". You win! Congratulations!"
    else:
        slay = True
    return slay
```

and assign it:

```
slay = testDeath(playerH, enemyH, enemy)
```

---

You could rearrange the function to make it neater:

```
def testDeath(pHealth, eHealth, enemy):
    """Test whether the player or enemy is dead."""
    if pHealth <= 0:
        print "You have lost the fight, better luck next time."
        return False            
    elif eHealth <= 0:
        print "You have slain the {0}. You win! Congratulations!".format(enemy)
        return False
    return True
```

Note the use of `str.format` and docstrings as well as the more logical structure.

Comment: Good catch! I guess the asker could also define `slay` as `global slay` inside the `testDeath` function, but I like your solution better.

Comment: @TheVelcromancer yes, I tend not to recommend `global` unless *absolutely* necessary!